# How to tell the difference between octane-1-ol and oct-1-ene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, alcohols

How to tell the difference between octane-1-ol and oct-1-ene? The things I can do are:

- check their solubility in water
- use bromine water
- use $\ce{KMnO4}$
- use sulfuric acid

I assumed that checking the solubility would be a good idea because of the presence of an alcohol but will I notice a difference since the alcohol has 8 carbon atoms. And they all react with bromine water, $\ce{KMnO4}$ and $\ce{H2SO4}$. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Do you have access to IR or NMR?

Answer (score 2):

Alkene is best characterized, then, by its property
of decolorizing both a solution of bromine in carbon tetrachloride  and
a cold, dilute, neutral permanganate solution (the Baeyer test). Both
tests are easily carried out; in one, a red color disappears, and in the other, a purple color disappears and is replaced by brown manganese dioxide.

Answer (score 0):

See whether in addition of Br₂ in CCl4 it gives red color or not ,It is a test to see the presence of the double bond and you can try Lucas test on the alcohol

Answer (score 0):

In a decent university chemistry lab you could try treatment with ozone, followed by triphenyl phosphine or reduction with zinc / acetic acid and then steam distillation. The octene will form formaldehyde and heptanal while the octanol should do nothing.